# javascript malformed objects send to aspmvc app

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I tried to create an object in javascript, I have my code that creates my object based on the user interface.

```
function skill(name,level){
    this.name= name;
    this.level= level;
 }
```

I create a new object

```
//in any event
var newSkill = new skill(nameSk,lvlSk);
```

Put the value in a hidden input

```
 SkillsList.push(newSkill);                    
 $('#id_ListSkills').val(SkillsList);
```

in HTML

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ListSkills" id="id_ListSkills" />
```

And in C# Controller

```
 public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            var skillssss = collection["ListSkills"];
            ....
```

In var skillsssss i get `skillssss = "[object Object],[object Object]"`

i tried debug javascript code with alerts

```
  var newSkill = new skill(nameSk,lvlSk);
  alert(newSkill); raise-> [object, Object] //Error
  alert(newSkill.name); raise-> correct name value
  alert(newSkill.level); raise-> correct level value
  SkillsList.push(newSkill); 
  alert(SkillsList); raise-> [object, Object],* (by the number of objects) //Error
```

i use jquery.

**How I can get the information to display correctly?**

thank you very much for your answers

Comment: The value of an element can only be a string, you can't set the value to arrays or objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @adeneo states, you are simply pushing an array of complex types into a string. You need to deserialize it. You can do that pretty easily using [Crockford's JSON.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Then it will simply be a case of:

```
$('#id_ListSkills').val(JSON.stringify(SkillsList));
```

http://www.json.org/js.html

You could then parse the JSON server side. I wouldn't really recommend it as best practice, but it's a way to defibrillate what you already have going.